# a sorted map of the faces to letters

Tags: java, dictionary

> Returns the mapping of faces to letters for this die. The faces are identified using the Integer values 1 through 6, and the returned map is sorted on its keys (the face numbers). For example, the die with faces:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
>
> having letters:
>
> C, M, I, O, U, T
>
> would return the map whose toString method would produce the following string:
>
> {1=C, 2=M, 3=I, 4=O, 5=U, 6=T}

So this is what I have so far, but i do not think it works also it is giving me error:

```
public SortedMap<Integer, String> getValueMap() {
    
    SortedMap<Integer,String> sm=new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
       
        sm.put(new Integer(1), "A");
        sm.put(new Integer(2), "A");
        sm.put(new Integer(4), "E");
        sm.put(new Integer(3), "E");
        sm.put(new Integer(5), "G");
        sm.put(new Integer(6), "N");
        Set s=sm.entrySet();

        Iterator i=s.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)i.next();
            int key = (Integer)m.getKey();
            String sValue=(String)m.getValue();
            
        }
        return "Key :"+key+"  value :"+sValue;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using an array of String (or, honestly, char)?  Your keys are small, sequential, positive integers with no gaps.  An array gives you better lookup time and is, by definition, sorted.  Put it behind a SortedMap interface that does bound checking and you're done.

Comment: What is the error that it is giving?

Comment: The error is almost surely that `key` and `sValue` are used outside of the block they were defined in.

Comment: And `"Key :"+key+"  value :"+sValue` is certainly not a `SortedMap` object

Comment: the error is this: my Set, Iterator, and Map.Entry is raw type. I have no idea what does that mean? please help troubleshoot my code. @MatthewFarwell

Comment: I have to return the key and value so that my toString will call it. That is why I am trying to use it outside while loop.@Olathe However, can anyone help me change that to for loop?

Comment: @user2197569: You should just return the `Map`. `toString` can be called directly on the `Map`. For example, in your main method: `Map<Integer, String> zomg = getValueMap(); System.out.println(zomg.toString());` You can even leave off the `toString()`, because `println` will do that for you.

Comment: the problem is my method is not doing what is to be done. That is why i posted here. I need to know the problem here first. Then I will do the printing part. However, thank you @Olathe I will keep the suggestion in mind.

Comment: There are tons of errors. Your `return` statement is outside the loop but tries to access variables which exist inside the loop only. It tries to return a `String` whereas the method is declared to return a `SortedMap`, you are using the generic types `Set`, `Iterator`, and `Map.Entry` without specifying type arguments (though you should use a for-each loop anyway) and don’t write `new Integer(…)` where writing the number itself is sufficient.